# Increase in Stratification late monsoon in Bay of Bengal

Tags: oceanography, salinity

I am involved in an experiment in the Bay of Bengal, letting moorings for a year long period and doing ship cruises. We have observed (from mooring CTDs) that the Brunt Vaisala frequency has increased almost by a magnitude of 10^1 during the late Indian monsoon period (September-December). The depth of measurement is 0-100 metres. Year 2016.

Possibility 1: Drifting of instruments and hence wrong measurements?
Possibility 2: Any process which can create such an increase in stratification.

Possibility 2 is my question. The whole water column shows a similar increasing trend in stratification which kind of negates Possibility 1. So, could you please help with some process insight on the kind of ways this can happen? For some inputs: Bay of Bengal gets very huge amount of fresh water during Monsoons.

Comment: magnitude of 10^1? Do you just mean 10?